# Vim and Macvim tags: How to handle them

Tags: discussion

I frequently come across questions tagged with both vim and macvim tag and quite often the macvim tag is not related to the question. So, how do I handle this situation? Should I remove the macvim tag?

As you can see from a simple [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim+macvim) there are a lot of questions tagged with both tags and they would be just fine with only the vim one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with any mis-tagging, editing to remove an incorrect tag is a good idea. Where multiple tags are used, removal of any redundant ones is a good idea.

the sanity check is to ask yourself if that tag adds anything of value to the question. In the case of vim and macvim, I can't think of any circumstances where both would be necessary.